# Textarea not represented on AngularJS form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

```
<form name="newPostForm" ng-submit="" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Post</label>
        <textarea name="postArea" class="form-control" width="500" height="400" required></textarea>
        <p ng-show="newPostForm.postArea.$invalid">Post content is required.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Post"></input>
</form>
```

The validation part (`<p ng-show="newPostForm.postArea.$invalid">Post content is required.</p>`) doesn't appear. It *does* apear when `ng-show="newPostForm.postArea === undefined"`, meaning `postArea` is `undefined`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
newPostForm.postArea.$invalid
```

to

```
newPostForm.postArea.$error.required
```

Also, I would suggest you to use `$dirty` to check if the user has interacted with the input. Otherwise, the 'content is required' error would appear by default which isn't ideal in my opinion. You can use `$dirty` like this:

```
newPostForm.postArea.$error.required && newPostForm.postArea.$dirty
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `newPostForm.postArea === undefined` according to Angular.